# how do we bake for lookup fields on cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-bake

I am exploring CakePHP's bake function and I used the latest CakePHP (3.6.1) followed some tutorials to bake the MySQL structure and it worked fine except that I expected the related fields with a foreign key constraint on my table need to be templated with the corresponding lookup field. Please tell me how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your table definitions and relations need to follow [akePHP's Database convetions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#database-conventions) in order to be detected by bake properly.

If you are **not** following the conventions then I can see two other options:

1. (more difficult) attempt to update bake itself to work with what you have.
2. Use bake as it is, but after the code has been generated manually add the table relations in your code. See [Linking tables together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)